# XML Schema assert loop validation

Tags: xml, xsd, assert, assertion, xsd-1.1

my XML structure looks like the following:

```
<myElement>
    <start>0</start>
</myElement>
<myElement>
    <start>5</start>
</myElement>
<myElement>
    <start>7</start>
</myElement>
<myElement>
    <start>14</start>
</myElement>
```

Now my validation rule is the following: Each "myElement" element will contain a "start" element. The integer value of this element can not be less than the previous "myElement" -> "start". So for example this would be invalid:

```
<myElement>
    <start>14</start>
</myElement>
<myElement>
    <start>7</start>
</myElement>
```

How can such a rule look like as a `xs:assert`-element?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Such an assert should fit your needs:

```
<xs:assert test="max(preceding::start) &lt; number(.) or empty(preceding::start)"></xs:assert>
```

In the first part, it is checked that the greatest preceding `start` value is still lower than current value being check.

The second part (`or empty(preceding::start)`) is just to overcome failure of the first part because the very first `start` tag won't present any value to be compared against.

It should be added in your associated schema that way -- the wrapping `complexType` being the content model of `myElement`:

```
               <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element name="start" type="xs:integer" />
                   </xs:sequence>
                   <xs:assert test="max(preceding::start) &lt; number(.) or empty(preceding::start)"></xs:assert>
               </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Could you please explain this rule a bit and where it should be placed in the XML?

Comment: It's done. Since you were talking about `<xs:assert>`, I assumed you were already quite comfortable with XML Schemas

Comment: Good answer. But I think its better to compare only with the previous *start* node using *preceding::start[1]* instead of calculate the maximum of the previous *start* nodes.

Comment: @potarne It works quite well but I have one problem with that solution. If you have multiple `myElement`-elements than this script will not work if the value of the `start`-element is less than in a previous 'myElement'-element. This should not be a problem